# How to sum multiple columns?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

my question is: is it possible to sum multiple columns and get the total of every column? I'm using this query:

```
SELECT borrower, SUM(collateral_amount) AS collateral_amount, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdraw_amount, SUM(total_amount_to_treasure) as total_amount_to_treasure, SUM(id) as id 
FROM loans 
GROUP BY borrower
```

But that result is not what I want . What I would like to get is for example collateral_amount: 30000 (second image)

[image: first image]

[image: second image]

And I would like to get this as a result:

```json
{  
"collateral_amount": "600000", //The total sum of the collateral_amount column  
"id": "10", //The total sum of the id column  
"withdraw_collateral": "30000", //The total sum of tthe withdraw_collateral column  
"total_amount": "90000" //The total sum of the total_amount  
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the task to sum all columns then you shouldn't use `group by`:

```
SELECT SUM(collateral_amount) AS collateral_amount,
   SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdraw_amount,
   SUM(total_amount_to_treasure) AS total_amount_to_treasure,
   SUM(id) AS id
FROM loans;
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I did that and it works pretty well. Thank you!